# How to append the result from each iteration into the CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sending the numerical field into for loop and calculating the max, min and percentile. I want to store each result (last print statement) into the csv file. I am literally struck here.

Each iteration in the for loop prints result like below:

```
emp_id, 10, 23, 45.4
```

I want to save these results in a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\spanda031\Downloads\test_19.csv')
#abc=data.dtypes
#print(abc)
df = data.select_dtypes(include='number')
cols = df.columns.values
print(cols)
arr = df.values
#print("new array ", arr)
#with open(r'C:\Users\spanda031\Downloads\test_19.csv') as f:
#    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    #get fieldnames from DictReader object and store in list
#    headers = d_reader.fieldnames
#    print(headers)
for line in cols:
        #print value in MyCol1 for each row
        #print(line)        
        v3=np.array(data[line])
        #print(v3)        
        print(line,",",v3.min(),",",v3.max(),",",np.percentile(v3, 25))
```

Comment: You're probably looking for either the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or the numpy [tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) functionality

Comment: You can use `python your_script.py >> your_file.csv` to append to an existing file.

Comment: Actually i am going to run the python script as standalone resource and i will create hive table on top of that csv file

Answer (score 0):

This way i could resolve it.

```
res_df=line,v3.min(),v3.max(),np.percentile(v3, 25),np.std(v3)      
    with open('C:\\Users\\spanda031\\Downloads\\abccc.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writerows = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writerows.writerow(map(lambda x: x, res_df))
```